# How to manipulate tinyMCE content using jQuery in WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

For last two days I have been searching for a way to manipulate tinyMCE content using custom button in WordPress. Using `editor.getBody()`, I was able to get content and manipulate it easily but I don't know how to get cursor position or selected element. I tried `getContent` but that behaves differently.

What I am doing is this: when user clicks the custom button I need to find it's certain parent element and then manipulate it. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works.
You can use the setup tinymce config parameter:

```
setup : function(ed) {

    ed.on('init', function(e){
        $(ed.getBody()).bind('change', function(e) {
            // do your magic here if e.target is your button!         

        });
    });
}
```

An other way to get the node of your caret in the editor is to call:

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id').selection.getNode();
```

Comment: I will need to go through documentation for setup config parameter. But 'getNode() ' answers my question. Thanks.